# Update text in Statusbar is not showing changes in first panel with different VCL theme used

Tags: delphi, statusbar, delphi-xe5

I have a statusbar with 3 panels. When I change the text of them in runtime, it is not changed in the first one (index 0).

I see, this is happening only if other VCL theme is chosen (f.e. Cyan Dusk).

Initial design texts are:

```
StatusBar.Panels[0].Text := '1';
StatusBar.Panels[1].Text := '2';
StatusBar.Panels[2].Text := '3';
```

And in the runtime I changed it:

```
StatusBar.Panels[0].Text := '11'; // this is not changed visually
StatusBar.Panels[1].Text := '22';
StatusBar.Panels[2].Text := '33';
```

I tried also all this code after, nothing worked:

```
Application.ProcessMessages;
StatusBar.Refresh;
StatusBar.Update;
Refresh;
```

I tried it also in the blank new application, the same issue.

When I try to debug it, in Code Inspector I see, the value has been changed also for index 0.

Also I tried this:

```
procedure TMainForm.StatusBarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(StatusBar.Panels[0].Text); // 11
  ShowMessage(StatusBar.Panels[1].Text); // 22
  ShowMessage(StatusBar.Panels[2].Text); // 33
end;
```

But still in the Statusbar panel index 0 is only `1`.

**Note:** this is happening only if different VCL theme is used.

Is this bug in VCL themes? How can I evoke to update changed text?

**UPDATE:**

When I set `StatusBar.StyleElements := StatusBar.StyleElements - [seClient];` it is working also for the first panel. But why without this it is working only for panels with index > 0?

Comment: If you have access to the VCL source code, look at the implementation of `TStatusBar.StyleElements` and see for yourself why `seClient` is making a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it is bug in VCL themes. This solved the issue, and also updated text in the `StatusBar.Panels[0]`:

```
StatusBar.StyleElements := StatusBar.StyleElements - [seClient];

Application.ProcessMessages;

StatusBar.Panels[0].Text := '11'; // now the text is updated visually
StatusBar.Panels[1].Text := '22';
StatusBar.Panels[2].Text := '33';

Application.ProcessMessages;

StatusBar.StyleElements := StatusBar.StyleElements + [seClient];

Application.ProcessMessages;
```